# Action of $D_{2n}$ on pairs of opposite vertices of a regular n-gon

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions, dihedral-groups

Having some difficulty understanding the solution to this problem.

> We have an action of $D_{2n}$ on set $A=\left\{{\left\{\overline{a},\overline{k+a}\right\}\mid1\leq a\leq k}\right\}$
>
>  and
> $s.\left\{\overline{a},\overline{k+a}\right\}=\overline{-a},\overline{-k-a}$
>
> where  geometrically $s$ flips the n-gon over the line passing through the vertices labelled $n$,$k$.  Bars denote equivalence classes $\bmod n$.

I can't understand this since for $n=4$  that would map $(1,3)$ to $(-1,-3)$

However $1\neq-1\bmod4$  and $3\neq-3\bmod4$.

Please guys, help me understand what I'm doing wrong here..?

[image]

Comment: I suppose those sets of opposite vertices should be $\{\overline{a}, \overline{n + a}\}$? Or instead, the group would be $D_{2k}$ rather than $D_{2n}$?

Comment: $\left\{\overline{a},\overline{n+a}\right\}$ would pair $(1,1)$ not opposites?  $D_{2k}$ would be of order 4 - $\left\{r,s,sr,1\right\}$  still containing $s$  so dont see how that could change it  ? *unless i am mistaken.  it states earlier in the solution ' Assume $n=2k$ is an even positive integer '.

Comment: Have you quoted the description fully? It doesn't make grammatical sense.

Comment: Is it the same as this webpage? [Google cache link](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:N_e54IGUQcQJ:https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/compute-the-kernel-of-an-action-of-dih2n-on-an-n-gon/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) So $n=2k$ and so on?

Comment: @ChrisCulter  yes it is from the crazy project df solutions.  Skipped a few details but feel free to ask if any questions..  Still cant figure it out ! (3 hours later) !

Comment: Okay, but... what exactly is the question? You're right that $s$ maps $\{\overline{1},\overline{3}\}$ to $\{\overline{-1},\overline{-3}\}$. You're right that $\overline{1}\neq\overline{-1}$ and $\overline{3}\neq\overline{-3}$. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @ChrisCulter  if this is the case then this line in the solution appears to be contradictory  $s.\left\{\overline{a},\overline{k+a}\right\}=\overline{-a},\overline{-k-a}$   bars denote equivalence classes..

Comment: The notation $s\cdot$ means that a function is being applied: the action of $s$. It's like saying $f(x)=y$. It's not a claim that $x=y$.